# Probability of intersection of row and column

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve a problem in which I have to guess the location of hidden items in a grid. To simplify the problem I have taken just 1 row and 1 column.

Lets say we have a horizontal row with 7 boxes and a vertical column with 4 boxes. The column and row intersect. I know that 5 of the 7 boxes in the horizontal row contain an 'X' and 1 of the 4 boxes in the vertical row contain an 'X'.

Individually I could say that each box in the horizontal row has a 5/7 chance of containing an 'X'. And each box in the vertical column has a 1/4 chance of containing an 'X'.

But what is the chance of the box where the column and row intersect containing a box? My first guess was the union rule, but that doesn't seem right to me, any thoughts? Thanks

Another way to ask this question might be: person A says it will rain tomorrow, he is right 70% of the time. Person B says it will rain tomorrow, he is right 40% of the time. What is the chance it rains tomorrow? Are these two the same thing?

Comment: I should note that by intersect I mean like a crossword puzzle intersects with rows and columns

Answer (score 1):

- Let $X$ be the event that the common box contains a check.
- Let $R{=}5$ be the event that the row of seven contains five checks.
- Let $C{=}1$ be the event that the column of four contains one check.

You assume distribution without bias so: $\Pr(X\mid R{=}5) = 5/7, \Pr(X\mid C{=}1) = 1/4$, and that's okay.

However, you wish to find: $\Pr(X\mid R{=}5, C{=}1)$ and this does not give you enough information to proceed.

That is, of course, the distribution of checks on the grid to tell you: $\Pr(R{=}5),$ $\Pr(C{=}1),$ $\Pr(R{=}5, C{=}1)$.

---

> Another way to ask this question might be: person A says it will rain tomorrow, he is right 70% of the time. Person B says it will rain tomorrow, he is right 40% of the time. What is the chance it rains tomorrow? Are these two the same thing?

In this case you know the probabilities of it raining when they say it will, $\Pr(R\mid A)=70\%,$ $\Pr(R\mid B)=40\%$ , but don't know the probabilities that they will say it will, separately or together, $\Pr(A),$ $\Pr(B),$ nor $\Pr(A,B)$ .   Thus you can't find the probability that it will rain when they both say it will, $\Pr(R\mid A, B)$ .

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What additional information would I need?

Comment: @Phil: Some way to assertain $\Pr(R{=}5),\; \Pr(C{=}1),\; \Pr(R{=}5, C{=}1)$

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to use the given data is to take it combinatorially. We study different ways of placing the Xs constrained by the rules that the row should have exactly five of them and the column exactly one.

If we assume the intersection is empty, then the X of the column must be on one of the three other boxes. The five Xs on the row must be on the six remaining boxes, and there are exactly $\binom 65=6$ ways of placing the five Xs in them. Altogether we have $3\cdot6=18$ configurations of Xs with the intersection empty.

OTOH if we have a cross in the intersection, then we have no choice about the placing of the Xs on the column. We do need to place the other four Xs of the row into the six other boxes. Those four boxes can be selected in $\binom 64=15$ different ways, so there are fifteen legal configurations of Xs with a cross in the intersection.

If (that may be a big IF) we are to assume that each legal configuration is equally likely, this means that the probability of finding an X in the intersection is
$$
P=\frac{15}{15+18}=\frac{15}{33}=\frac5{11}.
$$

If the question is to have a definite answer I think this is the way to do it. But it also means that the question is one of combinatorics rather than probability.

When you have more columns and rows, it may become increasingly difficult to enumerate the alternatives, and give a combinatorial answer.

I don't have anything to say about the weathermen. That question has no obvious combinatorial interpretation.

Comment: If the method of placing the Xs is known in detail, then we can, of course, say more.

Comment: Thanks, this seems reasonable

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by defining events $A$ and $B$.

$A$: Finding an 'X' on the horizontal row.

$B$: Finding an 'X' on the vertical row.

You are looking for an actual intersection: $P(A\cap B)$, which can be stated as "Finding an 'X' on both the horizontal and the vertical row".

where $P(A) = 5/7$ and $P(B)=1/4$

Then, we know that $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B) = 0.17857$ since they are independent events.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I went through by hand and did a smaller example. I had a row with 5 boxes where 4 had an 'X'. I had a column with 4 boxes where 1 had an 'X'. The column and row intersect. So the boxes in the row have a 4/5 chance of having an 'X' and the boxes in the column have 1/4 chance. Using your formula the chance of the box where the row and column intersect is is 20%. But when I went and drew out all the possibilities by hand, there were 7 total possibilities and 4 had an 'X' in the intersecting box, for 57%.

Comment: The events you describe are not independent.